# Then sum of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{3^n}$ lies in the interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Let $(a_n)_n$ be sequence of positive real numbers such that 
>   $$a_1=1, \, a_{n+1}^2 -2a_na_{n+1}-a_n=0$$ for all $n \geq1$
>   Then sum of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{3^n}$ lies in the interval
>
> (A) $(1,2]$;  (B) $(2,3]$; (C) $(3,4]$; (D) $(4,5]$.

My work. I found that $a_{n+1}=a_n +\sqrt{({a_n}^2+a_n)}$ then i tried to put this value in summation , but got stuck because of root .any suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Robert $a_{n+1}=a_n +\sqrt{({a_n}^2+a_n)}$ then i tried to put this value in summation , but got stuck because of root .any suggestion

Comment: So can you use that to approximate $a_n$? You aren't looking for an exact sum, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $a_{n+1}=a_n +\sqrt{a_n^2+a_n}$ and therefore for $n\geq 1$,
$$2a_{n}=a_n +\sqrt{a_n^2}<a_{n+1}\leq a_n +\sqrt{a_n^2+a_n^2}=(1+\sqrt{2})a_{n}$$
which implies, together with $a_1=1$, that for $n>1$,
$$2^{n-1}< a_n\leq  (1+\sqrt{2})^{n-1}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: ya .i got it .answer is option A. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that ${a_n}^2 \geq a_n$? What if $a_n<1$?

Comment: Also can we find the exact sum?

Comment: @Rhaldryn Note that $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n +\sqrt{({a_n}^2+a_n)}>a_n$. So $a_n^2\geq a_n$.

Comment: @Rhaldryn I don't know if there is a closed form for the exact sum.